# Doctrine proxy getter makes PHP app down with segmentation fault

Tags: php, docker, doctrine, xdebug

PHP 8.0 + Doctrine 2 + Xdebug + Docker.

When the script tries to execute any getter from generated proxy PHP app dies with segmentation fault.

F.e. I have this getter:

```
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isActive(): bool
    {

        $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'isActive', []);

        return parent::isActive();
    }
```

Then I debug it step by step, just after `$this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'isActive', []);` this lane it will be 502 error.

Edited nginx.conf with all fastcgi timeouts, buffers, proxy timeouts, buffers, etc.

Also I have updated Doctrine 2 to the latest version.

Comment: Please read at https://xdebug.org/reporting-bugs as to how to file a bug report with the authors of Xdebug. The best chance of getting this fixed if you can provide a (short) code example that you can run from the command line with "php myscript.php".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because of version of xdebug. On version 3.3.1 there is a bug. I installed 3.1.15 and all ok

Comment: If you want to make sure that this will be fixed in newer versions, **please** file a bug report. Installing older versions isn't the solution